# singular value decomposition in EE paper

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have matrix $B = USPP'S'U'$ where P' is the conjugate transpose of P and (U,S,V) are the SVD of some matrix A and P is diagonal can I say that $B=SPP'S'$? i am trying to understand how the authors [of this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7752562/?reload=true) go from equation (15) to equation (16) thanks

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the paper is behind a paywall.  You'll have to write out what exactly equations (15) and (16) are.

Comment: The answer to your question as literally stated is no: it is not generally the case that $USPP'S'U' =SPP'S'$, even if $U$ is orthogonal/unitary.

Comment: thank you , i will try to edit the my post now to put all equations

Comment: Before you edit: [see this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360) on how to format mathematical expressions on this site; you may find it useful.

Comment: ok i put one image because it is not allowed to put more i appreciate your trying to help also i will use the instruction of this page to write the full model  if you need

Comment: Well, that works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $AW_t W_t^H A^H = U\Lambda U^H$, and $U$ is unitary (that is, $U^H U = UU^H = I$).  For convenience, I write $M = U^H \Lambda U$ for some matrix $M$. With that said, there are two important facts from matrix analysis that are applied here:

**Fact 1:** For any [analytic matrix function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_polynomial) $p$, we have
$$
p(M) = p(U\Lambda U^H) = Up(\Lambda)U^H
$$
for example, if $p(x) = [(x + \sigma^2)^{-1}x]^2$, then we find that
$$
p(M) = [(M + \sigma^2 I)^{-1}M]^2 = 
U[(\Lambda + \sigma^2 I)^{-1}\Lambda]^2U^H
$$
**Fact 2:** For any matrix $Q$ and any unitary matrix $U$, we have 
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(UQU^H) = \operatorname{Tr}(Q)
$$

Comment: yes, thank you, i put more information in the image U is unitary because it is from the SVD of A

Comment: See my edit.  And of course, note that since $\Lambda$ is diagonal, it is easy to compute $p(\Lambda)$.

Comment: now if $M = B^HU^H \Lambda UB$ where B is not unitary is $p(M) = [(M + \sigma^2 I)^{-1}M]^2 = 
U[(B^H\Lambda B + \sigma^2 I)^{-1}B^H\Lambda B]^2U^H$

Comment: @husamwedyan no.